# Get the record id of a dynamically populated table in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have added records to a table that contains values in two text boxes and a button per each row. How can I get the record number of a particular button clicked by the user?

[image]

```
<table id="myTable">
</table>  
             
<script>
    
        var table=document.getElementById("myTable");
        var i=0;
        for(i; i<3; i++)
        {
            var row = table.insertRow(i);
        
            var cell0=row.insertCell(0);
            var element0=document.createElement("input");
            element0.type="text";
            element0.value = "Hello : " + i;
            cell0.appendChild(element0);
        
            var cell1=row.insertCell(1);
            var element1=document.createElement("input");
            element1.type="text";
            element1.value = "Welcome : " + i*2;
            cell1.appendChild(element1);
        
            var cell2=row.insertCell(2);
            var element2=document.createElement("input");
            element2.type="button";
            element2.value = "Clcik : " + i*i;
            element2.onclick = function show_id() { alert("Record ID"); }
            cell2.appendChild(element2);
        }
        
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you use an `index` for tracking the record?
Hoping this is the use case you are looking for. Include more details in case you need anything other than this.

```html
<table id="myTable">
</table>  
             
<script>
    
        var table=document.getElementById("myTable");
        var i=0;
        for(i; i<3; i++)
        {
            const recordId = i+1;
            var row = table.insertRow(i);
        
            var cell0=row.insertCell(0);
            var element0=document.createElement("input");
            element0.type="text";
            element0.value = "Hello : " + i;
            cell0.appendChild(element0);
        
            var cell1=row.insertCell(1);
            var element1=document.createElement("input");
            element1.type="text";
            element1.value = "Welcome : " + i*2;
            cell1.appendChild(element1);
        
            var cell2=row.insertCell(2);
            var element2=document.createElement("input");
            element2.type="button";
            element2.value = "Clcik : " + i*i;
            element2.onclick = function show_id() { 
            alert("Record ID - " + recordId); 
            }
            cell2.appendChild(element2);
        }
        
</script>
```